# Azure Function Python Model 2 in Docker container

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am failing to get a minimal working example running with the following setup:

- azure function in docker container
- python as language, specifically the ["new Python programming model V2"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#programming-model)

I followed the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-python#create-supporting-azure-resources-for-your-function) but added the V2 flag, specifically:

```
 # init directory
 func init --worker-runtime python --docker -m V2
 # build docker image
 docker build -t foo .
 # run functions locally
 docker run -p 80:80 foo
```

Whatever I tried, the runtime seems to not pick up the auto generated http trigger function

```py
# function_app.py (autogenerated by func init ...) 

import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="hello") # HTTP Trigger
def test_function(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse("HttpTrigger1 function processed a request!!!")
```

I think the relevant part of the logs is:

```
info: Host.Startup[327]
      1 functions found
info: Host.Startup[315]
      0 functions loaded
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Generating 0 job function(s)
warn: Host.Startup[0]
      No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostHttpRoutesManager[0]
      Initializing function HTTP routes
      No HTTP routes mapped
```

because when I use the "programming model V1", then the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostHttpRoutesManager` actually prints some info about the mapped routes.

How can I fix this? Is this not supported at the moment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems there are ongoing changes on [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3275). I was able to get it working by changing the environment variables in the auto generated dockerfile:

```
# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
    AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags=EnableWorkerIndexing \ # added by me
    AzureWebJobsStorage=UseDevelopmentStorage=true # added by me 

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

Comment: FYI for anyone developing using only the portal & VS Code, all you need to do is add the application setting (environment variable) `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags` with the value `EnableWorkerIndexing` in the Settings > Configuration section of the portal and then re-deploy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please confirm if we need to add *Real Azure Blob Connection String* for the 'AzureWebJobsStorage' parameter or `UseDevelopmentStorage=true' is sufficient?